# Adding a ListView on top of MapView in Xamarin Android using C# (Not Xml)

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

What I'm trying to do is writing the ***Xamarin Android*** code for the attached image (Which is ***Xamarin iOS***)

As we can see in the attached Image, we have a UITableView with floor numbers (1, 2 and 3).

How can I add a `ListView` in Android using **C# (Not XML)** to have the same result?

Here's a code snippet of the code I'm using.

But the problem is that my `ListView` is always under the `SearchBox` which is not what I want. I want the `ListView` to be at the bottom of my screen.

```
        private void CreateLayout()
    {
        // Create a new vertical layout for the app
        var layout = new LinearLayout(this) { Orientation = Orientation.Vertical };

        // Search Bar
        _mySearchBox = new AutoCompleteTextView(this) { Hint = "Search rooms or people..." };
        layout.AddView(_mySearchBox);

        //Auto Complete Drop Down List View
        _searchListView = new ListView(this);
        layout.AddView(_searchListView);

        // Progress bar
        _myProgressBar = new ProgressBar(this) { Indeterminate = true, Visibility = ViewStates.Gone };
        layout.AddView(_myProgressBar);

        // Floors List View
        _floorsTableView = new ListView(this);
        _floorsTableView.LayoutParameters = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(100, 150);
        _floorsTableView.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;
        var adap = new ArrayAdapter(this, Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem, new List<string>() { "1", "2", "3" });
        _floorsTableView.Adapter = adap;
        _floorsTableView.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;

        layout.AddView(_floorsTableView);

        // Add a map view to the layout
        _myMapView = new MapView(this);
        layout.AddView(_myMapView);

        // Show the layout in the app
        SetContentView(layout);
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you switch to a `RelativeLayout` instead of using a `LinearLayout` to host your views. `LinearLayout` inherently wants to position stuff according to its orientation, while `RelativeLayout` gives you more freedom and power to arrange views.

Also keep in mind that the order you add views to your host container matters. So in your case I would add the `ListView` last. This way you will ensure that the list draws on top of anything else.

Also you need to fully specify LayoutParams for each view!

```cs
var root = new RelativeLayout(this);

_mySearchBox = new AutoCompleteTextView(this) { Hint = "Search rooms or people..." };

_myMapView = new MapView(this)
{
    Id = View.GenerateViewId()
};

_floorsTableView = new ListView(this)
{
    Id = View.GenerateViewId()
};

var searchBoxParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
searchBoxParams.AddRule(LayoutRules.AlignParentTop);

var mapParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent);

var listParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(100, 150);
listParams.AddRule(LayoutRules.AlignParentStart);
listParams.AddRule(LayoutRules.AlignParentBottom);
listParams.SetMargins(16, 0, 0, 16);

root.AddView(_myMapView, mapParams);
root.AddView(_mySearchBox, searchBoxParams);
root.AddView(_floorsTableView, listParams);

SetContentView(root, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent));
```

You will also want to convert the dimensions to `px` from `dp`:

```cs
private int DpToPx(int dp)
{
    return (int)TypedValue.ApplyDimension(ComplexUnitType.Dip, dp, Resources.DisplayMetrics);
}
```

This way your dimensions will scale according to display density.

Comment: This one will work perfectly. Just have two questions. The search box looks transparent, is there a way to make it default (Not Transparent)? The second question is about the `DpToPx` method, you mean call it when setting the Width and Height of the `FloorsListView `?

Comment: The search box is transparent by nature. Usually the top area you see in the top of the screen shot you provided is a Toolbar, it supports showing menu items and search bars and stuff like that. As for DpToPx. I would use it for any exact dimension, so for margins, padding, and the for the size of your list. Preferably I would make that list a RecyclerView and use wrap_content to allow it grow as big as it needs.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `RelativeLayout` to put an object over another object, then use `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` to specify where you want it. So you need:

```
var layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
```

And then using `LayoutRules.AlignParentBottom` and `LayoutRules.AlignParentLeft`:

```
// Floors List View
_floorsTableView = new ListView(this);

// Create parameters for the listview
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams parameters = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(100, 150);
parameters.AddRule(LayoutRules.AlignParentBottom);
parameters.AddRule(LayoutRules.AlignParentLeft);

_floorsTableView.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;
var adap = new ArrayAdapter(this, Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem, new List<string>() { "1", "2", "3" });
_floorsTableView.Adapter = adap;
_floorsTableView.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;

// Add the listview to the layout with parameters specified
layout.AddView(_floorsTableView, parameters);
```

I didn't test it so you may have to play with width and height layout parameters or such.